# Laravel middleware rule not working if controller is executed via app('App\Http\Controllers\SubController')->SubControllerFunction()

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

In my Laravel 9 project, I have main controller -> **HomeController**.

Inside **HomeController** I have several functions where other controller is called:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function callSubController()
    {   
        app('App\Http\Controllers\SubController')->SubControllerFunction();
    } 
}
```

​
in my **SubController** I want to add middleware rule SubControllerMiddleware in __construct function, but it is not working.

```
class SubController extends Controller
{   

  public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'SubControllerMiddleware']);
        
    }    
}
```

Is there a way how to call middleware inside SubController?

Comment: you can't call controllers like this ... the router has to have the controller method be an end point so it can actually resolve the controller and build a middleware stack to pass the request through ... the only thing that calling the `middleware` method does is add an element to an array on the controller (that is it) it has zero functionality without the router

Comment: The Http Kernel is responsible for calling the route along with associated middleware so if you want the middleware to be called you need to send a request through the Kernel.  For example you might be able to do `$response = app(Kernel::class)->handle(Request::create('url for request'));` however it is far more readable and appropriate to create helper methods instead of going this route

Answer (score -4):

To resolve this issue fellow these steps :
1- Define the middleware in your

> app/Http/Kernel.php

file, if it's not already defined. Middleware can be global or specific to your controller or route.

```
// Example middleware definition
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'customMiddleware' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomMiddleware::class,
];
```

2- use it inside controller

```
// Apply the middleware to this method
        $this->middleware('customMiddleware');
```